# Extracting rows by specific cell values VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My process consists:

1. Going through the cell values in Column A of sheet 1
2. Checking to see if the cell values from sheet 1 match with any of the values in Column C of sheet 2
3. If there is a match, copy the entire row in which there is a match from Sheet 2 to Sheet 3.

I posted my code below but somehow can't get it to work.

```
Sub Test1()
 Dim Name As String
 Dim lastrow As Long
 Dim Cell As Variant

 lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 2 To lastrow

Name = Cells(i, 1)
If Name <> "" Then
     For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C4000")
         If Cell.Value = Name Then
             matchRow = Cell.Row
             Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
             Selection.Copy

             Sheets("Sheet3").Select
             ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
             ActiveSheet.Paste
             Sheets("Sheet2").Select
         End If
    Next
End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Overflow!*  You'll have to expand on "can't get it to work".  Are you getting an error?  Where?  What have you tried? Could you please [edit] your post to provide more information?  Also, check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) as well as tips at "[ask]" and about how to create an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop through every cell in Sheet2!C:C.

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim i As Long, c as variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            c = Application.Match(.Cells(i, "A").Value2, Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(3), 0)
            If Not IsError(c) Then
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(c).Copy _
                  Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The Macro did a good job looping through the rows which matched between Sheet 1 and Sheet 2, but errors occurred in pasting those rows to Sheet9

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the .Value of the cell.

```
Name = CStr(Cell(i, 1).Value)
```

Also, there is a built in function to determine if a cell is empty.

```
If Not IsEmpty(Cell(i, 1).Value) Then
```

Also, I would suggest setting a reference to the worksheet instead of just saying Cells()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("wb name here")

ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Where your errors were coming from was it was getting confused what sheet was selected. So you needed to be more explicit, as below.

```
    Sub Test1()
 Dim Name As String
 Dim lastrow As Long
 Dim Cell As Variant

 lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 2 To lastrow

Name = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
If Name <> "" Then
     For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C4000")
         If Cell.Value = Name Then
             matchRow = Cell.Row
             Sheets("Sheet2").Select
             ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
             Selection.Copy

             Sheets("Sheet3").Select
             ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
             ActiveSheet.Paste
             Sheets("Sheet2").Select
         End If
    Next
End If

Next


End Sub
```